# Trying to think of borrowed English words that parse "ti" as ティ or as チ。

Tags: words, pronunciation, loanwords, phonology

I often trip up in guessing the pronunciation of words that have been borrowed into Japanese from English where the original pronunciation had "ti" in it.

For example, I might say ネイチブ instead of ネイティブ.

I realised this is because the way those words are rendered in Japanese isn't consistent. Sometimes it's ティ, but sometimes it's チ.

So far I can think of the words below, but I'd be grateful if you could suggest more. **EDIT: To be clear, I would just like people to list a few they can come up with off the top of their heads, for the purpose of new discoveries. No need for an exhaustive list.**

### ティ

ネイティブ (native)
ティー (tea)
パッティー (patty)
ティーシャツ (T-shirt)

### チ

チップ　(tip)
モチベーション (motivation)
チーム (team)
チケット (ticket)
チベット (Tibet)

Comment: To clarify; are you just wanting a list of the different times チ or ティ are used? Or the reasoning behind why this happens?

Comment: Also T-Shirt is most commonly Tシャツ not ティシャツ。

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder I think this is about pronunciation rather than spelling.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31629/discussion-on-question-by-sebu-trying-to-think-of-borrowed-english-words-that-pa).

Comment: @sebu If you're asking for a list, I don't think it's really possible to do that in the SE format.  There would just be too many words.  A user has flagged the question to be closed as 'Too Broad'.  If you asked if there was a way to figure out if it'd be ティ or チ based on the English pronunciation, that would work, although it wouldn't be very useful since there isn't one :-(  Could you answer the question The Wandering Coder asked in the first comment?

Comment: If you are asking why it happens, then this post may be related 
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21649/standard-for-writing-pronouncing-loanwords-%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a4%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%83%bc-v-s-%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%82%a6-etc

Comment: @snailboat Are you saying there is no consistent way to tell if a loanword will use チ or ティ? Because that's a question that's been on my mind for a while.

Comment: @Kurausukun: Um, look up in a dictionary?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply! @TheWanderingCoder, I just wanted a list – not an exhaustive one, but I thought it would be interesting for people to share some they came up with off the top of their heads. In Yuu's post below there were a few words that surprised me, so it was quite helpful.

Comment: @Cebu No problems. There are a lot of words (some of which can use either the ち or てぃ depending on who is talking / the situation and in *some* cases this can be a personal preference. The general rule I have found is, that words that appeared prior to the post-War Showa period (specifically the period around the 1964 Tokyo Olympics) use チ. Due to both the end of the Second World War (and thus aggressiveness against foreign words and ideas) and the want to appear global for the Olympics there was a great deal of English that entered both the standard Japanese lexicon and society at large.

Comment: That, coupled with an influx of American and other English-speaking servicemen led to pronounciations closer to their English counterparts being transliterated (as opposed to easier to pronounce [for Japanese] sounds - such as チ). *Most* post-Olympic words you find in Japanese (that aren't decided by businesses) will follow this pattern, however there are exceptions to this rule. It is to note as well, that this spelling choice is not limited to English-based transliterations (this year for instance, school text books were changed to feature the proper Spanish pronunciations of some words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this question is very broad, but I'll just list some I can think off the top of my head. I will be adding more as I come across them online.

Do you want to include medical/scientific terms? There's a lot of them.

ティ

```
ティーンズ　　　 teens
ティアラ 　　　　tiara
ティシュ 　　　　tissue
ティーピーオー 　TPO
ティルト         tilt
フェスティバル   festival
```

チ

```
チクタク       tictac
チタン         Titan/Titanium
チタニウム     Titanium
チッカー       ticker
チルダ         tilde
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I wasn't aware of most of these ones so it was interesting.